# Questions about NullReferenceException too easily marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

In the review queue I frequently find questions that are marked as duplicates of this question:

[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/861716)

This isn't always helpful. Many people know perfectly well what the exception means, they just don't know in their *specific* case what it's caused by, or it is only mentioned as a side effect of their actual problem. Being directed to a question explaining the exception and possible fixes only in general terms (however useful in itself) is close to being patronized or LMGTFY-ed.

The overstretched review queue could do without these "duplicates". Also, questions get closed unjustly when others blindly confirm the close reason.

I was thinking of leaving a comment below the question, asking people to take a second look before picking it as a "duplicate source".

Would this be useful at all? Or is it me now who is patronizing? Or should I leave this to a moderator?

If useful, what could be an appropriate text?

Comment: Show some examples

Comment: 'Most people know perfectly well what the exception means." I disagree completely. *Most* people posting NRE questions have no clue and haven't bothered to even check in their debugger. Nuke every single question on sight.

Comment: One example (of many): http://stackoverflow.com/q/24110163/861716

Comment: @AnthonyPegram In many cases you're right, but there are questions where people don't even ask about the NRE, it only happens to be an insignificant part of the problem.

Comment: On your sample, I actually (and sheepishly) agree, the NRE is secondary, the main problem is reading from a config file. I wouldn't have used my gold badge auto nuke on that one.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram OK, and maybe I shouldn't indicate the problem as too common - editing.

Comment: here is [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24007458/1070452) .   Where even **Jon Skeet** seems stumped (gasp!)!  It should be noted that neither question is tagged as a Dupe of the touchstone one, which shows that people are reading the question and not simply auto-Duping when they see the term NullReference.  (I cant see the close votes referred to in the comment on Gert's example).

Comment: Ummm Jon is asking for a minimal example that demonstrates the behaviour @Plutonix. That doesn't mean he's stumped, it means the OP didn't provide enough information.

Comment: @Plutonix Well, if the first sentence is "I know this exception occurs when in C# object is null", people should be near brain dead to mark it as duplicate of the NRE question. Of course you can find examples where this doesn't happen. The problem is, it *does* happen - more often than I think should be necessary.

Comment: Oh, and the question in my example was actually closed as we were speaking, for the reason I mentioned, but Anthony reopened it.

Comment: If the question is not a "debug my NPE for me" question, but can be mistaken for one, the question is unclear. Which is reason enough to close it.

Comment: @Raedwald This is too easy and simply not true. Some reviewers just don't read.

Comment: FWIW, a new example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24118305/861716. Yes, the question should be closed, but it says: "My question is: What is virtual? And When will I use it?" Again, the NRE is collateral damage. Do close reasons matter, or not?

Answer (score 2):

If people are incorrectly closing questions then there are number things that you can do:

1. Vote to reopen the question once it has been closed. If you have a gold badge in one of the  **orignal** tags on the question your vote is binding.
2. Leave a comment indicating how this question isn't a duplicate - not really ideal.
3. Edit the question to emphasise the *real* problem rather than the null reference exception which may just be symptom of something more tricky to solve.

In the [example you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24110163) it's not all clear what the actual question is, so an edit may just be what is needed.

Unfortunately I don't think there's a lot we can do as moderators/high rep users to prevent people flagging/voting to close.

There'd have to be a change to the code to warn the user that they are selecting a common duplicate target and are they really sure that this question is a duplicate of that one. However, I'm not sure it would be of sufficient benefit.

Comment: But this is what I'm trying to prevent: dealing with each individual incorrect close vote.

Comment: @GertArnold Editing is the answer. If the question is unclear so people can't see that the NRE is a *symptom* of something then they will tend to vote to close.

Comment: @GertArnold: And depending on the threshold in their heuristics, they'll either close as duplicate of NRE or for "unclear what you are asking". (The threshold for NRE-duplicate might be incredible low ;-) )

Comment: @Deduplicator I doubt that. I often think that reviewers pull the trigger a soon as they read the word NRE. But if the question should be closed because it is unclear, so be it, but for *that* reason.

Answer (score 1):

You might* be able to say that's the wrong close reason; but in this case, the question *still should not have been re-opened* (or closed immediately as 'unclear what you're asking' if it were somehow re-opened).

The question is quite unclear, even after several editors have tried to edit it into shape.

The OP says, "It gives me a NullReference Exception" and he refers to a line of code above where there could be several places where the NRE comes into play.  We can guess all day long, but because he hasn't broken the code down line by line and let us know *exactly* what the system thinks is Null (and giving us the stack trace to the right line number afterwards), we can't answer his question.

*It could be answerable by the information in the listed duplicate*, but even then, it may not .  The person who re-opened did so because they don't believe it's a duplicate, but even using their words: *They're not sure that's the case!*:

> This ***appears to be a case*** of figuring out how to read a config file from one project in another. The NRE is a symptom, but it's not the actual issue.

---

*I say *might* because this question is not a good example of a duplicate being 'wrong'. At best it's a coin toss, made in good faith.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It's not about this specific question. This is the "pars pro toto pitfall" discussions at meta often evolve in.

Comment: Come on. This was evidently the wrong close reason. There may have been a close reason, but that's not the issue.